# Which one performs better in Java? Creating object or getting from cache twice?

Tags: java, performance, low-latency

The object has 6,7 fields.
`cache.get()` is a map read.
Which one is faster?

```
obj temp = cache.get(key);                              // temporary object creation
Int id = temp != null ? temp.getId() : null;
```

or

```
Int id = cache.get(key) != null ? cache.get(key).getId() : null;       // cache read twice
```

For Java with low latency, which of the above is better?

Comment: Your first one isn't *creating a temporary object*. It's assigning a value to a temporary variable.

Comment: The only thing potentially eating any perfomance here is the `cache.get` - why would you call it twice?

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, you are **not** creating a temporary reference - you are assigning an existing object to a local variable that will be go out of scope soon.

The first snippet is preferable, although if `cache` is a simple `HashMap` it would probably be unnoticeable.
It becomes more important if `cache` is something fancier, e.g., some sort of synchronized map that needs to handle concurrency.

Comment: would there be any cost is assignment, any shallow copy ?

Comment: In Java, assigning an object doesn't perform any copying of the data, shallow or otherwise - it's just another reference to the same object. You can think of it as assigning a pointer - the only thing you're copying is the address in memory.